# CSS - Switch não muda de texto quando é clicado

Tags: css, asp.net

Tenho uma checkbox que transformei num switch para o utilizador poder escolher "Sim" ou "Não": sim quando é clicado, não quando não é clicado. Quando o switch não é clicado, aparece o texto "Não" conforme esperado. No entanto, quando carrego no switch, o texto não muda para "Sim" como era esperado. Gostaria de perceber o que poderá estar a causar este problema.

O meu código CSS é o seguinte:

```css
  
    .switch {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 105px;
        height: 34px;
    }
    
    .switch input {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .slider {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #ccc;
        transition: .4s;
    }
    
    .slider:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 26px;
        width: 26px;
        left: 4px;
        bottom: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        transition: .4s;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + .slider,
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .slider {
        background-color: #2196F3;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:focus + input[type="hidden"] + .slider,
    input[type="checkbox"]:focus + .slider {
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + .slider:before,
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .slider:before {
        transform: translateX(69px);
    }
    
    .slider.round {
        border-radius: 34px;
    }
    
    .slider.round:before {
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .slider.round:after {
        content: 'NÃO';
        color: white;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .slider.round:after {
        content: 'SIM';
    }
```

```html
<label class="switch">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo CandidatarOutros é necessário." htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, checked = True }" id="CandidatarOutros" name="CandidatarOutros" type="checkbox" value="true"> 
                    <div class="slider round"></div>
                </label>
```

Quanto ao código HTML, este não é bem código 100% HTML. Como estou a trabalhar em ASP.NET, estou a usar um dos helpers deles para criar checkboxes:

```
<label class="switch">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo CandidatarOutros é necessário." htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, checked = True }" id="CandidatarOutros" name="CandidatarOutros" type="checkbox" value="true"> 
                    <div class="slider round"></div>
                </label>
```

Comment: Coloca o HTML também

Comment: HTML adicionado.

Comment: E qual o output do html, no browser mesmo.

Comment: Tal como indiquei na minha questão :"Quando o switch não é clicado, aparece o texto "Não" conforme esperado. No entanto, quando carrego no switch, o texto não muda para "Sim" como era esperado."

Comment: O @ViniciusCainelli quer saber qual o HTML renderizado, porque o que você postou é o que será interpretado no servidor.

Comment: É só clicar em Inspecionar no elemento e copiar o HTML

Comment: Ah sim. Peço desculpa, devo ter interpretado mal. Este é o HTML renderizado: <input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo CandidatarOutros é necessário." htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, checked = True }" id="CandidatarOutros" name="CandidatarOutros" type="checkbox" value="true">

Comment: substitua esse do comentário na sua pergunta, ou adicione

Comment: Coloquei o input renderizado no post original.

Comment: bom eu peguei o codigo que voce postou e coloquei na ferramenta do proprio stackOverflow e o codigo funciona normalmente, por isso acho que o problema seja outro. Pode ser no seu navegador ou utilizo do ASP.NET